# Cannot find record using MongoJs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, multiplayer

I have a login system connected to mongodatabase but the result is always 0 even if i'm searching for a record I know.

```
thePass = passWord.value
theUser = userName.value

loginButton.onclick = function() {

    console.log(theUser)
    socket.emit('login', {username: theUser, password: thePass})

}
```

---

```
const mongojs = require("mongojs")
const db = mongojs('localhost:27017/shadowRiseDB', ['player'])

var correctDetails = function(data, cb) {
        db.player.find({username: data.username, password: data.password}, function(err, res) {
            console.log(res.length)
            if(res.length > 0)
                cb(true);
            else
                cb(false);
            });
        }

socket.on('login', function(data) {
        theDetails = data;
        correctDetails(theDetails, function(res){
           if(res) {
               socket.emit('loginDetails',{success:true});
           } else {
               socket.emit('loginDetails', {success:false});
           }
       })
    })
```

The if statement won't trigger as res is always 0 when trying to find something in my db. What is goig on?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the res to an array before checking length:

```
if(res.toArray().length>0){
    ...
}
```

Comment: This would be correct. Find returns a ```cursor``` rather than an array of documents. You have to first use the built in toArray method to convert the cursor to an array. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find